# How to trigger unique event on div which has several duplicates? (Angular 2)

Tags: angular

So I'm creating several divs in an ngFor loop. If I click one of the divs, I want to add a class to only the div that has been clicked.

Currently I'm just using a boolean flag on [ngClass] to present a test case, but I'm not sure how I could modify something like this so each div generated could have a unique flag.

Here is a plunk to demonstrate;

https://plnkr.co/edit/tCWTi7SJdvs2UXpQMYpe?p=preview

I'm struggling to come up a solution to this, I want to avoid targeting the DOM with elementRef but I'm not sure if it's possible?

(I've never actually used this feature since the angular docs flag a security risk, so if I have to use this any advice on how it could be done would be greatly appreciated!)

Code is below - Hopefully I've explained it well enough, let me know if you need more info.

---

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="testCase" 
    *ngFor="let data of data" 
    (click)="onSelect()"
    [ngClass]="{'selected': selected}">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  selected: boolean = false;

  data:[];

  onSelect(){
    this.selected = !this.selected
  }

  constructor() {
    this.data = ['test1', 'test2']
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.testCase {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.testCase:first-child {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.testCase:last-child {
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.testCase:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.selected {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either trace the `index` of the array, or use the value itself. The last thing will only work if you have unique values, so let's stick with the index:

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OWH0nQquMK9uWo31TwGD?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="testCase" 
    *ngFor="let data of data; let i = index;"  
    (click)="onSelect(i)" 
    [class.selected]="selectedIndex === i">  
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  selectedIndex: number;

  data:[];

  onSelect(index:number){
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.data = ['test1', 'test2']
  }
}
```

You see you can use `[class.selected]` to only add that specific class if a certain case is `true`. On the other hand you see you can get the index of the current element within the `*ngFor` loop using `let i = index`

Comment: Thanks! I guess it could be used the same way with ngIf?

Comment: You can't put both *ngIf and *ngFor on the same element. But yes, child elements can have an *ngIf statement :)